# AM Charts Defined Colour Scale on Heat Map

Tags: amcharts

I want to create a Heat Map and I am using the following example from AmCharts4:

[Heat Map Example](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/pLOXgO)

How do I define the maximum and minimum values for the colour scale, rather than just let it use the values from the data set?

Here is the line of code I think I need to modify but not sure how:

```
series.heatRules.push({target:columnTemplate, property:"fill", min:am4core.color("#ffffff"), max:am4core.color("#692155")});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heat map rules](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/iheatrule/) can take a `minValue` and `maxValue` if you don't want them to derive the range from your dataset:

```
series.heatRules.push({
  target:columnTemplate, 
  property:"fill", 
  min:am4core.color("#ffffff"), 
  max:am4core.color("#692155"),
  minValue: 2000,
  maxValue: 5000
});
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/25818b21a348be0330b006992922d25b/)

Comment: Thanks works perfectly for the Heat Map, but the Heat Legend doesn't use these new values. How can I use these values for the legend as well please?

Comment: It's the same properties in the legend, too.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry one more question, is it possible to add a 3rd colour to the scale? So it goes from Green, to amber to red for example?

Comment: Not currently, I'm afraid. They are planning on implementing this at some point but they don't have an ETA at this time.